# How to extract a static value from a type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types

The code looks like this.

```
  public class One<T> where T : Two {
    public static int Y;  
    static One() {
      // Y is to be initialised with the Z value from T
      // this code does not compile
      // Y = T.Z;
    }
    public int X {  get { return Y; } }
  }

  public class Two {
    public static int Z = 42;
  }

  public class Three {
    public void Main() {
      One<Two> a = new One<Two>();
      Console.WriteLine("X = {0}", a.X); // should say 42
    }
  }
```

The idea is very simple: initialise the static value in a class from another static value in another class passed as a type parameter. There is nothing 'unsafe' about this, but the natural way to do it does not compile (see code).

I've searched SO and found a few near misses, but nothing that hits the spot. I've tried a few things including reflection, but to no avail. Any solution or even hints much appreciated.

Comment: Why does it need to be a static and not an instance variable? How about an explicit interface implementation so you could put it in the where constraint?

Comment: If you change it in `Y = Two.Z;`, it will probably print it, but it's a meh...

Comment: What did you gain? You know that everything you'll ever find in a One is a Two and hence has a Z so why not just say `Console.WriteLine("X = {0}", Two.Z); // should say 42`? I think the example is so contrived it's lost any sense of why it's a good idea; could you post a less contrived example?

Comment: @CaiusJard - You're spot on with this comment. If we could write `public virtual static int Z = 42;` then it might make sense to allow this OP's construct, but we can't so it doesn't.

Comment: @CaiusJard: the real example is trying to solve a complicated problem with lots of extraneous details. But the core is this: `One` will be a collection of `Two`s where both levels share a common unique identifier, `Two` can't know about `One`, and the collection might be empty. So `One` has to get its id from a static in `Two`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost looks like it should work.  Then you start typing `T.Z` and realize that your gut is agreeing with the compiler.  `T` is a type parameter, it isn't a full fledged type-y thing.

Anyways, this works:

```
static One()
{
    // Y is to be initialised with the Z value from T
    var typeT = typeof(T);
    var zFieldInfo = typeT.GetField("Z");
    Y = (int) zFieldInfo.GetValue(null);
}
```

Yeah, it uses reflection, but it's only ever going to be run once.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It feels like there ought to be a better way, but I think this is all there is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Flydog's given you something you could use; I just wanted to make a quick note about my/jimi/enigmativity's comments:

It feel like you're hoping to subclass Two at some point and change out the Z; you reason that if your new class Three, which has a static Z of 43 and derives from Two, is used in combination with One then you'll end up with an `.X` that is 43. The problem comes in that static things cannot be overridden; they're resolved at compile time and they can *look* like overriding is at play in certain circumstances, but it's actually overloading or hiding and the compiler is picking something with a particular name in a defined order out of the inheritance tree

Because static things don't inherit (and arguably don't need to because they are hence always known to you, the developer, at compile time) there isn't the expectation that one day someone will subclass your code and write :

```
One<Four> a = new One<Four>();
```

And your code will need to pick up whatever they set Z to and use it. You know your Zs and can use them appropriately at compile tine and they know their Zs and should use them appropriately. But I understood where you were going with the T.Z thing..

Comment: No subclassing isn't it. The problem is sharing a unique identifier between collection and member classes, when the only place the collection can get its id is from the class of the member. The inability to overload statics is certainly an impediment to other possible solutions.